# Why does subsequent calls to my function not update the visibility of the elements as intended?

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding some form validation and updating the visibility of a notification depending on the status code of an http request using:

```
function isValidEndpoint()
{
    var xmlHttp = null;
    var myurl = "/restyendpoint/" + document.getElementById("endpoint").value;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", myurl, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    if (xmlHttp.status == 409) {
        document.getElementById("sucnot").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("warnot").style.visibility="visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sucnot").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("warnot").style.visibility="hidden";
    }
}
```

When I load the page the elements are both invisible, on typing the first character I get the "That endpoints free" message (as the first character entered doesn't exist in the db).  From that point the visibility of the notifications doesn't change, even though I can confirm correct request/response from the "restyendpoint" validation.

Comment: Did you add console lines and see what the status is? Also synchronous requests are a bad idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Status is good: 409 and 200 for existing and nonexisting enpoints, as expected.  I thought xmlHttp.open(,,true) was for "use async": will rtfm, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having been provided with [Prior art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) by @Musa.  I amended my code as follows and it now works:

```
function isValidEndpoint()
{
    var xmlHttp = null;
    var myurl = "/restyendpoint/" + document.getElementById("endpoint").value;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {// request is done
            if (xmlHttp.status === 409) {// endpoint exists
                document.getElementById("sucnot").style.visibility="collapse";
                document.getElementById("warnot").style.visibility="visible";
            } else {//endpoint doesn't exist
                document.getElementById("sucnot").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("warnot").style.visibility="collapse";
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", myurl, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
}
```

So, setting async to true in the request, the xmlHttp object needs to check the status *when it returns*. What it was doing was immediately checking the status, and defaulting to always display a particular notification.